how to measure angular accuracy in x/y dimensions?
Imagine a coordinate system where the x axis is left-right, y is up-down, and z is straight ahead in front of me (or in front of the camera, to be more precise). Suppose I want to characterize a unit vector $(x,y,z)$, pointing away from the camera ($z > 0$), as a pair of angles that specify how much it deflects from $(0,0,1)$ in the $x-$ and $y-$ directions.
The easy and thing to do seems to be: take the angles $\arctan(x/z)$, $\arctan(y/z)$. If we imagine a plane orthogonal to $z$ placed at $z=1$, the line of the vector will intersect it at $(x/z, y/z, 1)$, so the idea is to project the  meeting point onto the $x,y$ axes and take the angles between it and $(0,0,1)$. This seems convenient, but I can't seem to find a standard name or reference for such a pair of angle "coordinates". These aren't the spherical coordinates $\theta, \varphi$, right? - because those aren't symmetric w.r.t. each other. Nor are these Euler angles, because those are made for applying rotation in sequence (and the order matters). Nor are these "azimith" and "elevation", which if I understand correctly, coincide with the spherical coordinate angles, once axes are chosen carefully.
So what are they? Are the drawbacks for using them to measure deflection from $(0,0,1)$, or, more generally, angular "deviation" separately in two dimensions of one vector from another? What should I be looking at instead?
